# How do I disable the guest account on Ubuntu 13.10 (Saucy)

Tags: 13.10, users

Yes! I want to get rid of the guest account on Ubuntu. How do I do this??

I do not want this account but neither I find it in `/etc/passwd` and `/etc/group` nor within the users by navigating to system Settings -> user accounts...

Answer (score 0):

1. Open `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-unity-greeter.conf` with root rights.
2. Append the line `allow-guest=false`
3. Reboot.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you can remove the account, but you can disable it : it won't be an option at login.

- Edit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

  ```
  sudo nano /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
  ```
- Add the following line at the end :

  ```
  allow-guest = false
  ```
- Save <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>O</kbd>
- Quit the text-editor <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>X</kbd>

---

Or in one command-line :

```
echo "allow-guest = false" | sudo tee -a /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

Comment: This did work well on earlier versions, but does not work on 13.10.

Comment: Well, I'm currently using this and it works. And I'm on 13.10.

Comment: So you created the file? Well then, because there's no `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` on 13.10 by default.

Comment: uuuh, yeah there is one by default^^

Comment: `man lightdm` confirms what I say (using 1.8.4, as it is by [default](http://packages.ubuntu.com/saucy/lightdm))

Comment: Very strange ^^ From 13.10, all options should be in the "numbered files" in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/`. But let's not argue about this, as long as everything works :)